# Multiple comparisons in foreach with an array of objects

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, conditional-statements

I have two arrays of objects.

$animals contains one object per animal with the properties 'id', 'sort' and 'alive' ("yes" or "no).

$inventory contains a matching object for every animal (matched on 'id') in $animals with the information (properties) 'id', 'type' and 'validated' ($true or $false).

I'd like to loop through all of my animals in $animals where "alive=yes" and:

1. Do nothing if "type=reptile" in $inventory.
2. Send animals to the vet where "validated=$false" in $inventory.

The code:

```
$animals = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{id=1;sort='cat';alive='yes'}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=2;sort='dog';alive='yes'}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=3;sort='mouse';alive='no'}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=4;sort='anaconda';alive='yes'}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=5;sort='cobra';alive='yes'}
    )

$inventory = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{id=1;type='mammal';validated=$false}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=2;type='mammal';validated=$true}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=3;type='mammal';validated=$false}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=4;type='reptile';validated=$false}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=5;type='reptile';validated=$true}
    )


foreach ($animal in $($animals.Where( {$_."alive" -eq "yes"} ))) {
    if ($inventory.Where( { (($_."id" -eq $animal."id") -and ($_."type" -eq "reptile")) } ))  {
        "Skip"
    } elseif ($inventory.Where( { (($_."id" -eq $animal."id") -and ($_."validated" -eq $false)) } ))  {
        "Email vet: $($animal) needs to be validated!"
    }
}
```

While this works perfectly fine, it's quite inefficient to loop through all of the "type=reptile" even though I'm not going to do anthing with them. It would be more efficient (and elegant) if I could somehow sort out the "type=reptile" directly in my foreach or prior to going into the foreach. Does anyone know of any way to sort out the "type=reptile" directly in the foreach, or before, in a more efficient way than in the example?

Comment: merge the two imported arrays into one array, then use a compound `Where-Object` test to include or exclude as desired.

Comment: As @Lee_Dailey suggests, I purposed to [add a Join-Object cmdlet to the standard PowerShell equipment `#14994`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14994) to facilitate an easy (`$animals |Join $inventory -on Id |Where alive -eq 'yes' ...`) syntax for this. Otherwise, you probably want to create a hashtable based on the `id` to link the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're *always* filtering on `id`, you might as well do that up front:

```
foreach($animal in $animals |Where-Object alive -eq yes){
  $filteredInventory = $inventory |Where-Object id -eq $animal.id
  # ...
}
```

If you want to assert whether *any* object in a collection satisfies a certain criteria, but you don't actually care about the resulting objects, there are a couple of things you can do:

### `... |Select-Object -First 1`

`Select-Object -First $N` has the ability to "abort" the pipeline early, so you could do something like:

```
foreach($animal in $animals |Where-Object alive -eq yes){
  $filteredInventory = $inventory |Where-Object id -eq $animal.id

  if($filteredInventory |Where-Object type -eq reptile |Select-Object -First 1){
    "Skip"
  }
}
```

### `.Where({...}, 'First')`

If you want to use the `Where()` extension method, you can ask it to similarly "abort early", by specifying the `First` selection mode:

```
if($inventory.Where({$_.type -eq 'reptile'}, 'First')){
  "Skip"
}
```

---

Assuming your real-life use case has more than 5 objects in each collection, a much better overall improvement would be to index the inventory using a hashtable:

```
$inventory = @{}
@(
    [pscustomobject]@{id=1;type='mammal';validated=$false}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=2;type='mammal';validated=$true}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=3;type='mammal';validated=$false}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=4;type='reptile';validated=$false}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=5;type='reptile';validated=$true}
) |ForEach-Object {
    # Index all objects in inventory by their id
    $inventory[$_.id] = $_
}
```

Now the initial lookup by id is going to be way faster than before, and since we know that each dictionary entry hold only one object, it'll be as simple as:

```
foreach($animal in $animals |Where-Object alive -eq yes){
  $inventoryRecord = $inventory[$animal.id]

  if($null -eq $inventoryRecord){
    Write-Warning "No inventory record exists for animal with id $($animal.id)"
    continue
  }

  if($inventoryRecord.type -eq 'reptile'){
    # skip
    continue
  }

  "Email vet: $($animal) needs to be validated!"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MathiasR.Jessen It helped me shave valuable seconds (more than a minute) in my real world use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, a `foreach` or `for` loop with an `if` condition is the fastest way there is in Powershell to filter arrays and `where-object` is the slowest.

As Lee_Dailey pointed out in the comment, in my opinion, the most elegant way is to merge both arrays but in this case and for your example this works fine considering that the count of `$animals` and `$inventory` will always be the same and both arrays will always be `ordered by ID`:

```
$animals = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{id=1;sort='cat';alive='yes'}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=2;sort='dog';alive='yes'}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=3;sort='mouse';alive='no'}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=4;sort='anaconda';alive='yes'}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=5;sort='cobra';alive='yes'}
    )

$inventory = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{id=1;type='mammal';validated=$false}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=2;type='mammal';validated=$true}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=3;type='mammal';validated=$false}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=4;type='reptile';validated=$false}
    [pscustomobject]@{id=5;type='reptile';validated=$true}
    )

for($i=0;$i -lt $inventory.Count;$i++)
{
    if($inventory[$i].Type -ne 'reptile' -and !$inventory[$i].validated)
    {
        "Email vet: $($animals[$i].Sort) needs to be validated!"
    }
}

PS /home/>
Email vet: cat needs to be validated!
Email vet: mouse needs to be validated!

This is the non elegant / ugly way:

$animals.where({$_.ID -in ($inventory.where({$_.Type -ne 'reptile' -and !$_.Validated})).ID}).foreach({
    "Email vet: $($_.Sort) needs to be validated!"
})

PS /home/>
Email vet: cat needs to be validated!
Email vet: mouse needs to be validated!
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first created a filtered inventory list with no reptiles. I'd also make it a lookup table for easier/faster referencing.

```
$inventorylookup = $inventory | Where-Object type -ne 'reptile' | Group-Object -Property Id -AsHashTable

$animals | Where-Object {$_.alive -eq 'yes' -and $_.id -in $inventorylookup.values.id} | ForEach-Object {
    if($inventorylookup[$_.id].validated -eq $true){
        Write-Host skip
    }
    else {
        Write-Host Email vet: $_.sort, ID $_.id, needs to be validated!
    }
}
```